# How to exclude saving properties on a model in .netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to either have a whitelist or a blacklist for preventing certain fields from being modified/updated when updating a model.

When we were using .netcore 2.2 this was working:

```
_context.Entry(user).Property(u => u.MiddleName).IsModified = false;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Is there something I need to change to have this working for .netcore 3.1?

Comment: Doesn't look like the api has changed...?

Comment: Are you hitting this issue? https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19131. Is the value saved to a real database, or just hanging around in memory?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes that seems to be the same issue I am dealing with. And this is saving to a postgres database.